# How can we reduce the effect and pain while experiencing results of bad karma?

Tags: karma

I am aware that we have to experience the results of Karma done by us. If I have done a bad Karma under the influence Maaya or Agnana(With out consciousness), How to reduce the effect of bad Karma. If experiencing result of bad karma is inevitable how can I make it less painful?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2971/36

Comment: A man who says he is bound remains bound; a man who says he is free becomes free. This popular saying is true: as you think so you become.

Comment: analogy like watching a movie (this is easier said than done!) - in a movie, we see some parts where Hero is on top and some parts where he is in lows, right? What if the movie was only filled with happy moments? Who will watch such a movie!? Noone. Everybody wants some highs and lows in the movie. The highs make them appreciate the lows and the lows make them appreciate the highs. Similar with life. If life was full of highs, we would easily lose interest. Look at life as a movie, where all highs are followed by lows and lows by highs. This will make one Jivan mukth (liberated while alive!)

Comment: also helpful is to remember that all events are temporary. Everything is like a passing cloud in this world and other worlds. No cloud remains forever. The Sun will come out. Similarly bright times ahead. No pain lasts forever and no pleasure lasts forever. Rejoice your failures for they make your success sweeter. Some inspirational quotes by Swami Vivekanandaji: “In a day, when you don't come across any problems - you can be sure that you are travelling in a wrong path”, Sir “All power is within you; you can do anything and everything. Believe in that, do not believe that you are weak" :)!!!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned one by Keshav. The above question asks how to negate the effect with *prayaschita* and why it's useful while this question asks for methods to lessen pain that is caused by inexorable past actions.

Answer (score 3):

The human mind cannot hold two thoughts at the same time. You can only hold one thought at a time. If you are conscious of God, thinking of God, then there is no room for pain. If you are thinking of pain, then there is no room for love of God. Think of God, love God. Krishna says (Gita 18. 65-66):

> Fix your heart on Me, give your love to Me, worship Me, bow down before Me; so shall you come to Me. This is My pledge to you, for you are dear to Me. Abandon all dharmas and come to Me alone for shelter. I will deliver you from all sins; do not grieve.

Asthvarka Samhita says (1.11) -

> A man who says he is bound remains bound; a man who says he is free becomes free. This popular saying is true: as you think so you become.

Be good and think of God alone and everything will vanish.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the [Imaginal Cells & The Caterpillar’s Job to Resist the Butterfly](http://augustocuginotti.com/imaginal-cells-caterpillars-job-to-resist-butterfly/) "inside"? Take this...

> A caterpillar crunches its way through its ecosystem, cutting a swath of destruction by eating as much as hundreds of times its weight in a day, until it is too bloated to continue and hangs itself up, its skin then hardening  into a chrysalis.
>
> Inside this chrysalis, deep in the caterpillar’s body, tiny things biologists call **‘imaginal disks’** begin to form. Not recognizing the newcomers, the caterpillar’s immune system snuffs them as they arise. But they keep coming faster and faster, then linking up with each other.
>
> Eventually the caterpillar’s immune system fails from the stress and the disks become **imaginal cells** that build the butterfly by feeding on the soupy meltdown of the caterpillar’s body.
>
> It took a long time for biologists to understand the reason for the  immune system attack on the incipient butterfly cells, but eventually they discovered that the butterfly has its own unique genome, carried by the caterpillar, inherited from long ago in evolution, yet not part of it as such (Margulis & Sagan, Acquiring Genomes 2002).

Thats the inevitable **Transformation** my friend! And **Pain** is when you resist it.

Don't you think the caterpillar feels PAIN in the process? Yes indeed, but eventually, you see, its ALL about you evolving into a better "You".

Everything thats happening, is happening for the sake of 'Balance'.

Believe me, the first thing you need to practice, is to **consciously** BREATH, feel yourself, the air moving in, feel your fingers, limbs. Realize yourself in the *Present*, because this where changes happen, this is where "YOU" exist, on this tiny "blue dot", called Earth, that glows with LIFE in this endless, dark emptiness. The only one place that matters, is this moment, and you ought to be here, and in fact, you ARE here.

So just **Breath-in the Moment...Breath-out the Past**, and your Future will be free of bondage.

And note that *Agyaan*, is NOT being "without consciousness", rather its about being *Without Awareness*.

Comment: Thx for posting about the imaginal cells & caterpillar to butterfly situation 

Answer (score 1):

I will share you my own experience, There is nothing as much effective as the name of Lord Maha Vishnu and Lord Shiva. One must continuously chant any name of Lord Maha Vishnu or Lord Shiva, you will get free from any bondage.

> Om Gam Ganeshay Namah
>   **Om Namah Shivay**
>   **Om Ramay Namah**
>   Om Krishnay Namah
>   Om Namo Bhagawate Vasudevay
>   Om Ham Hanumate Namah
>   Om Datatreya Namah

Simple. Just chant the name of any Lord who is your Guru. Have faith in your Guru. Just stop giving importance to any other activity in your life and start chanting GOD's name. Only God's name chanting can save any one from pain or any other thing. But you have to continuously chant God's name. The rule is you have to chant GOD's name 24 by 7, even when you sleep , chant God's name and think that GOD is with you. You should not have any ideas in mind. Just chant GOD';s name, you will survive.

By chanting you will enter in `Bhakti Yoga`, as a result your heart will automatically **surrender** unto GOD. Your only Goal is to chant Lord's name, by doing so you will reach your `GURU` - The ultimate Truth / Supreme Truth.

Answer (score 1):

Through three things: ***Mantra***, ***Mani*** and **Medicine**. Bad karma generally causes problems in the physical and mental level. While mental level pain can be reduced through right knowledge and attitude like other fellow  users have pointed out, physical level pains can be avoided through medicine and other means.

Due to past ignorance a misdeed has already been done, so that can't be undone. But God has given us knowledge and intelligence too through which we can try to minimize the effect. So for this the common three means are:

> **Mantra**: There are various mantras for propitiating planets that cause troubles in our life and there are also mantras for many other
>   requirements. In the past people used to use mantras to get rid of
>   pain and problems. Mantra's can be useful both for physical and mental
>   level of pain when accompanied with proper procedure and ritual.
>
> **Mani**: There are various jewel stones and *ratnas* (e.g. blue sapphire, red coral, etc.) which also help to some extent. So
>   astrologers usually recommend certain stones as per a person's
>   requirement.
>
> **Medicine**: Irrespective of whether you experienced a physical pain due to an accident or past bad action, the present action should
>   always be to take proper medicine to reduce the pain.

So to reduce the effect of inevitable bad actions, in the present any of the three should be used to lessen the pain. Regarding what *mantra*, *mani* or medicine should be used, it is described in many scriptures but should always be consulted and understood from a guru or the right person.

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently reading the Upanishads (Chandogya and Kena) and have been in general exploring the vedantic texts. From my understanding, At this point my teacher would say that you should ask yourself that, What is the nature of the pain and suffering that you so fear? To a mind which has reached an identification with the Universal existence (brahman) for it pain and suffering is just another experience just as is Joy.